Azure DevOps - JFrogNuget Error - Error occurred while executing task: Error: Command failed
My problem is similar to the one discussed in Error in jfrog-cli : The following error was received while trying to encrypt your password: Artifactory response: 404 404. however, i am using JFrog Cli V2 within Azure DevOps.
I have setup an artefact repository in Artifactory and I am using the JFrogNuGet to push a nuget in the the repository. full version of the task is below,
- task: JFrogNuGet@1
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    artifactoryConnection: 'JFrog Trial'
    targetDeployRepo: 'MYREPO'
    targetDeployPath: '/'
    pathToNupkg: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'

I am receiving the following error,
15:33:51 [Warn] (Attempt 1) - Failure occurred while sending GET request to https://artifactory.ORG.com/artifactory/api/security/encryptedPassword: Get "https://artifactory.ORG.com/artifactory/api/security/encryptedPassword": dial tcp: lookup artifactory.ORG.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host
15:33:51 [Info] executor timeout after 0 attempts with 0 milliseconds wait intervals
15:33:51 [Error] The following error was received while trying to encrypt your password: Get "https://artifactory.ORG.com/artifactory/api/security/encryptedPassword": dial tcp: lookup artifactory.ORG.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host
##[error]Error occurred while executing task: Error: Command failed: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jf/2.56.1/x64/jf c add "Antifactory-Test_20240624.3_nuget_deployer_1719243231436" --artifactory-url="https://artifactory.ORG.com/artifactory" --interactive=false --user='***' --basic-auth-only --password-stdin

I do not have access to user and password parameter for the service connection therefore i cannot use the solution mentioned in the above link.
I tried the below step with no luck before the Nuget Task. i get the same error for this task as well.
 - task: JfrogCliV2@1
   inputs:
     jfrogPlatformConnection: 'My-Connection'
     command: 'jf config add artifactory-server --artifactory-url="https://ORG.hiscox.com"'


I tested the JFrogNuGet@1 task in my pipeline with the Microsoft hosted agent, and it works without error. Your issue is different from the question discussed in the one you mentioned. That one is a 404 error. But your error is dial tcp: lookup artifactory.ORG.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host. This error indicates that the system is unable to resolve the hostname artifactory.ORG.com to an IP address. It seems a network issue. You should check your Network or Firewall settings on the agent you run the pipeline. You can also try to use the Microsoft hosted agent and see if it works.

@MiaoTian-MSFT you are correct. the problem goes away when using a hosted agent. please add your comment as an answer so that i can mark it.

Thanks for your update. I added the answer.

I tested the JFrogNuGet@1 task in my pipeline with the Microsoft hosted agent, and it works without error.
Your issue is different from the question discussed in the one you mentioned. That one is a 404 error. But your error is dial tcp: lookup artifactory.ORG.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host.
This error indicates that the system is unable to resolve the hostname artifactory.ORG.com to an IP address. It seems a network issue. You can check your Network or Firewall settings on the agent you run the pipeline.
You can also try to use the Microsoft hosted agent.
